# How to make sure that my list comprehension returns a list of strings that are not present in a different list?

Tags: python

I want to make a list comprehension that iterates through a list of strings, and only gives me back strings which are not present in another predefined list.

```
samples= ['abc', 'cab', 'bth', 'doc', 'bue']
unwanted= ['doc', 'bue']
wanted_samples= [sample for sample in samples if sample #checks if sample is present in unwanted list]
```

I have tried to set this up in a couple ways, but it has not worked yet. Any help would be great. It seems like something I should have figured out a while ago, but my brain has just not been cooperating with me today.

Comment: How does `if sample` know anything about `unwanted`? Perhaps you want to use `in` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing this

```
wanted_samples = [sample for sample in samples if sample not in unwanted]
```

if the sample is present in the unwanted list, the sample will not be added to wanted_samples

Answer (score 1):

use `not in`:

```py
wanted_samples = [sample for sample in samples if sample not in unwanted]
```

if it's a sample and your `unwanted` list has a lot of words, I suggest using set instead(`unwanted= {'doc', 'bue', ...}`). Time Complexity of membership testing for set is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use *not in* operator
`wanted_samples = [sample for sample in samples if sample not in unwanted]`